# How can I update user in django restfremework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a `RegisterSerializer` that presents all fields of the `User` model. Now my motive is a user can update his/her information. I have written code that not working. Can you please tell me where are the issues?

***views.py:***

```
class Profile(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]

    def get(self, request):
        users = User.objects.all()
        user = request.user
        serializer = RegisterSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    


    def patch(self, request):
        try:
            
            data = request.data
            serializer = RegisterSerializer(data=data, partial=True)

            print("==================",serializer)

            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(
                    {
                        'user': serializer.data,
                        'message': "Your profile has been updated"
                    },
                    status=status.HTTP_200_OK
                )
            else:
                return Response(
                    {
                        'user': serializer.errors,
                        'message': "Your profile could not be updated"
                    },
                    status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                )



            
        except IntegrityError:
            return Response(
                {
                    'user': None,
                    'message': "A user with that username already exists"
                },
                status=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT
            )
        
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return Response(
                {
                    'user': None,
                    'message': "An error occurred while updating your profile"
                },
                status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            )
```

***serializer.py:***

```
class RegisterSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            "username",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "email",
            "password"
        )

    def validate(self, data):
        if User.objects.filter(username = data['username']).exists():
             raise serializers.ValidationError("user already exist")
        return data
    
    def create(self, validate_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validate_data["username"].lower(),
            first_name=validate_data["first_name"],
            last_name=validate_data["last_name"],
            password=validate_data["password"],
            
            
        )
        print("End User======================", user)
        #user.set_password(validate_data["password"])
        user.set_password(validate_data["password"])
        user.save()

        return validate_data
```

***it returns:***

```
{
    "user": null,
    "message": "An error occurred while updating your profile"
}
```

Comment: are you sure, your patch method update method will update information against single instance or object? you are not getting an object that would be update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I improved the serializer of the patch and also RegisterSerializer class then it started to work:

```
def patch(self, request):
    try:
        userid = request.user.id
        user = User.objects.get(pk=userid)
        data = request.data
        serializer = RegisterSerializer(user, data=data, partial=True, context={'request': request})


class RegisterSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    blogs = BlogSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    mycomments = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            "username",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "email",
            "password",
            "blogs",
            "mycomments"
        )

    def validate(self, data):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        current_user_id = request.user.id if request and request.user else None
        if User.objects.filter(username = data['username']).exclude(id=current_user_id).exists():
             raise serializers.ValidationError("user already exist")
        return data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Profile(APIView):
     permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
     authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]       

     def get_object(self, pk):
        return ModelName.objects.get(pk=pk)

     def patch(self, request, pk):
        object = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = YourSerializer(object, data=request.data, partial=True) # set partial=True to update a data partially
    ---> rest of the code comes here   <---
```

Comment: thank you for your solution but I solved it last day

Comment: ok good to hear, best of luck